# Can I use cumulative distributed function in Gekko's intermediate variables?

Tags: python, normal-distribution, gekko

I'm trying to solve a nonlinear optimization problem using Gekko where one of my intermediate variables are calculated using a cumulative distribution function of a normal distribution, i.e. 1-CDF(μ,σ, Rs-X) where Rs is another Gekko intermediate variable and μ, σ and X are Gekko parameters/Python variables.

I've also implemented this using Gekko's if3 function that returns the number 1 if Rs-X is not positive.

```py
    n = len(df_inputs.index)    # rows
    surplus = m.Array(m.Var,(n,1))
    R_sns = m.Array(m.Var,(n,1))
    R_s = m.Array(m.Var,(n,1))
    pi_s = m.Array(m.Var,(n,1))
    for i in range (n):
        surplus[i,0].value =...
        R_sns[i,0].value = m.max3(x,surplus[i,0])
        R_s[i,0].value=m.Intermediate(0.88*R_sns[i,0])
        pi_s[i,0].value = m.if3(R_s[i,0]-x<=0,1,1-norm.cdf(R_s[i,0]-x,df_inputs['Mu'].iloc[i]*0.5,df_inputs['Sigma'].iloc[i]*0.707))
```

I'm getting a "TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()" on that last line of code above. This error seems to be caused by the intermediate variable Rs. I tried replacing that with a fixed number and the error went away.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "solve_v2.py", line 59, in 
>       pi_s[i,0].value = m.if3(R_s[i,0]-x<=0,1,1-norm.cdf(R_s[i,0]-x,df_inputs['Mu'].iloc[i]*0.5,df_inputs['Sigma'].iloc[i]*0.707))
>    ...
>     File "C:\Users\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\gekko\gk_operators.py", line 25, in **len**
>       return len(self.value)
>     File "C:\Users\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\gekko\gk_operators.py", line 137, in **len**
>       return len(self.value)
>   TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()

How do I get around this error?

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs because norm.cdf is not a Gekko function and cannot provide exact first and second derivatives to the gradient-based solver. If a function isn't in Gekko, there are few options such as: (1) request that the function is added by requesting the feature in the Gekko Github repository or (2) create an approximation of the function. One way to create an approximation of the stats.norm.cdf function is to create a cubic spline. Below is an example:

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import norm

# create cspline of CDF
xp = np.linspace(-5,5,100)
yp = norm.cdf(xp,loc=0,scale=1)
c = GEKKO()
x = c.Var()
y = c.Var()
c.cspline(x,y,xp,yp,True)

# use cspline of CDF in optimization problem
c.Obj((y-0.75)**2)
c.solve(disp=False)

# plot results
plt.figure()
plt.plot(xp,yp,5,'b-')
plt.plot(x.value,y.value,'ro')
plt.ylim([-0.1,1.1])
plt.show()
```

[image: Cubic spline of Cumulative distribution function]

If the spline approximation includes two dependent variables then the `bspline` function is a better choice.

One other issue with your script above is the use of the Gekko `if3` function. You can leave out the `<=` in your first argument. It is already implied as shown in the function help.

```
        Usage: y = m.if3(condition,x1,x2)
        Inputs:
           condition: GEKKO variable, parameter, or expression
           x1 and x2: GEKKO variable, parameter, or expression
        Output: GEKKO variable y = x1 when condition<0
                               y = x2 when condition>=0
```